# Yocto compilation

Tags: linux, yocto

I want regerate the 'modules' folder

not other

no code

In my yocto project I add modules , this is the row that I add in local.conf file.
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  "lighttpd curl libstdc++ bluez5"

In my target file system the new modules are present and I can run their.

root@imx6ull14x14evk:/mnt/lighttpd_tcs# lighttpd -f conf/lighttpd.conf
2019-07-01 14:09:50: (../../lighttpd-1.4.48/src/plugin.c.229) dlopen() failed for: /usr/lib/mod_proxy.so /usr/lib/mod_proxy.so: cannot open shared obj
ect file: No such file or directory
2019-07-01 14:09:50: (../../lighttpd-1.4.48/src/server.c.1141) loading plugins finally failed

How you can see the module run but othe files are missing.
I my host computer where is yocto project these files are present.
In the file that I put on target there aren't.
Infact the folder 'modules' in  ~/imx-yocto-bsp/Linux-RCA2/tmp/deploy/images/imx6ull14x14evk/ is old one and it is not update.
How can I update this folder with new modules ?

Answer (score 1):

In your meta layer, create a bbappend file for lighttpd as like:

```
recipes-common/lighttpd/lighttpd_%.bbappend
```

And then add the following lines into the recipe:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
 lighttpd-module-auth \
 lighttpd-module-fastcgi \
 lighttpd-module-proxy \
"
```

Then build lighttpd

```
bitbake lighttpd -c cleanall; bitbake lighttpd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lighttpd modules are split into separate packages in OpenEmbedded/Yocto: based on the error message you need to add the 'lighttpd-module-proxy' package to your IMAGE_INSTALL as well.

Also, for some reason the modules seem to get installed into $libdir (typically /usr/lib/) not into any 'modules' directory...